# Why do we need to call zero_grad() in PyTorch?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch, gradient-descent

Why does [`zero_grad()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.Optimizer.zero_grad.html) need to be called during training?

```
|  zero_grad(self)
|      Sets gradients of all model parameters to zero.
```

Answer (score 493, accepted):

In [`PyTorch`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch), for every mini-batch during the *training* phase, we typically want to explicitly set the gradients to zero before starting to do backpropagation (i.e., updating the ***W**eights* and ***b**iases*) because PyTorch *accumulates the gradients* on subsequent backward passes. This accumulating behavior is convenient while training RNNs or when we want to compute the gradient of the loss summed over multiple *mini-batches*. So, the default action has been set to [accumulate (i.e. sum) the gradients](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/autograd.html) on every `loss.backward()` call.

Because of this, when you start your training loop, ideally you should [`zero out the gradients`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.Optimizer.zero_grad.html#torch.optim.Optimizer.zero_grad) so that you do the parameter update correctly. Otherwise, the gradient would be a combination of the old gradient, which you have already used to update your model parameters and the newly-computed gradient. It would therefore point in some other direction than the intended direction towards the *minimum* (or *maximum*, in case of maximization objectives).

Here is a simple example:

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.optim as optim

def linear_model(x, W, b):
    return torch.matmul(x, W) + b

data, targets = ...

W = Variable(torch.randn(4, 3), requires_grad=True)
b = Variable(torch.randn(3), requires_grad=True)

optimizer = optim.Adam([W, b])

for sample, target in zip(data, targets):
    # clear out the gradients of all Variables 
    # in this optimizer (i.e. W, b)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output = linear_model(sample, W, b)
    loss = (output - target) ** 2
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

---

Alternatively, if you're doing a *vanilla gradient descent*, then:

```
W = Variable(torch.randn(4, 3), requires_grad=True)
b = Variable(torch.randn(3), requires_grad=True)

for sample, target in zip(data, targets):
    # clear out the gradients of Variables 
    # (i.e. W, b)
    W.grad.data.zero_()
    b.grad.data.zero_()

    output = linear_model(sample, W, b)
    loss = (output - target) ** 2
    loss.backward()

    W -= learning_rate * W.grad.data
    b -= learning_rate * b.grad.data
```

---

**Note**:

- The *accumulation* (i.e., *sum*) of gradients happens when [`.backward()` is called on the `loss` tensor](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/autograd.html).
- As of v1.7.0, Pytorch offers the option to reset the gradients to `None` [`optimizer.zero_grad(set_to_none=True)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/optim/optimizer.html#Optimizer.zero_grad) instead of filling them with a tensor of zeroes. The docs claim that this setting reduces memory requirements and slightly improves performance, but might be error-prone if not handled carefully.

Comment: Just to be sure.. if you don't do this, then you will run into an exploding gradient problem, right?

Comment: @zwep  If we accumulate gradients, it doesn't mean their magnitude increases: an example would be if the sign of the gradient keeps flipping. So it wouldn't guarantee you'd run into the exploding gradient problem. Besides, exploding gradients exist even if you zero correctly.

Comment: When you run the vanilla gradient descent do you not get a "leaf Variable that requires grad has been used in an in-place operation" error when you try to update the weights?

Comment: In other words , its done to set the variable delta_w and delta_b back to zero.

Comment: A follow-up question on this: so you're saying we shouldn't call optimizer.zero_grad() when training RNN models such as LSTM, for example?

Comment: Why `optimizer.zero_grad()` is before `output = linear_model(sample, W, b)` ?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have an additional question:
What happens if I have two networks net_A, and net_B which are interconnected? If I set `net_B.parameters()[i].requires_grad = False`, and then compute the gradient w.r.t `net_A`, Would the gradients of `net_A.parameters()` be affected by nonsense values stored in `net_B.parameters()`?

Comment: Can someone answer @Loqz's question? I'm wondering about that too. Do you need to call `zero_grad()` when training an **RNN**?

Comment: do you do this for validation as well or only train? I also have loss.backward in validation step. I understand we shouldn't do this in test phase since it is only one epoch.

Comment: @AlaaM.  `.zero_grad` needs to be called at some point to [throw away outdated information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76645793/365102).

Comment: "we typically want to explicitly set the gradients to zero before starting to do backpropagation (i.e., updating the Weights and biases)" Actually the term backpropagation refers to only error accumulation. Weight update is the step after backpropagation. That distinction is often overlooked but it becomes important in this discussion. I would understand errors being accumulated before the weight update but after the weight update, I would expect the resetting of gradients automatically.

Answer (score 28):

Although the idea can be derived from the chosen answer, I feel like I want to write that explicitly.

Being able to decide when to call `optimizer.zero_grad()` and `optimizer.step()` provides more freedom on how gradients are accumulated and applied by the optimizer in the training loop. This is crucial when the model or input data is big and one training batch do not fit on the GPU.

Here in [this example](https://github.com/google-research/xtreme/blob/master/third_party/run_classify.py), there are two arguments, named `train_batch_size` and `gradient_accumulation_steps`.

- `train_batch_size` is the batch size for the forward pass, following the `loss.backward()`. This is limited by the gpu memory.
- `gradient_accumulation_steps` is the actual training batch size, where loss from multiple forward pass is accumulated. This is **NOT** limited by the gpu memory.

From this example, you can see how `optimizer.zero_grad()` may followed by `optimizer.step()` but **NOT** `loss.backward()`. `loss.backward()` is invoked in every single iteration (line 216) but `optimizer.zero_grad()` and `optimizer.step()` is only invoked when the number of accumulated train batch equals the `gradient_accumulation_steps` (line 227 inside the `if` block in line 219)

Also, someone is asking about the equivalent method in TensorFlow. I guess [tf.GradientTape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape) serves the same purpose.

Comment: This relates to training large models with limited GPU memory. Your ideas are expanded on in this nice post: https://towardsdatascience.com/i-am-so-done-with-cuda-out-of-memory-c62f42947dca

Answer (score 9):

##### Why gradients?

The gradients *suggest* to the optimizer what direction to step in. Every time you process a batch of inputs with `.backward()`, you accumulate "suggestions" of where to step. Notice that a suggestion is much weaker than a *decision*. When you  call `optimizer.step()`, the optimizer uses these suggestions to make actual *decisions* of where to actually step. These decisions may be influenced by the learning rate, past steps (e.g. momentum), and past weights (e.g. SWA). The optimizer reads the suggestions and then steps in a direction that it hopes will minimize future losses.

```
loss.backward()        # Compute gradients.
optimizer.step()       # Tell the optimizer the gradients, then step.
optimizer.zero_grad()  # Zero the gradients to start fresh next time.
```

##### Why zero the gradients?

Once you've completed a step, you don't really need to keep track of your previous suggestion (i.e. gradients) of where to step. By zeroing the gradients, you are throwing away this information. Some optimizers already keep track of this information automatically and internally.

With the next batch of inputs, you begin from a clean slate to *suggest* where to step next. This suggestion is pure and not influenced by the past. You then feed this "pure" information to the optimizer, which then *decides* exactly where to step.

Of course, you can decide to hold onto previous gradients, but that information is somewhat outdated since you're in an entirely new spot on the loss surface. Who is to say that the best direction to go next is still the same as the previous? It might be completely different! That's why most popular optimization algorithms throw most of that outdated information away (by zeroing the gradients).

---

---

##### Another alternative: Deleting gradients completely (instead of zeroing)

Instead of zeroing the gradients, you can also delete them entirely. The [PyTorch performance tuning guide](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/tuning_guide.html#use-parameter-grad-none-instead-of-model-zero-grad-or-optimizer-zero-grad) suggests:

```py
# INSTEAD OF:
model.zero_grad()
# or
optimizer.zero_grad()
```

```
# CONSIDER:
for param in model.parameters():
    param.grad = None
```

...but one of the developers mentions [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/in-optimizer-zero-grad-set-p-grad-none/31934/2) in a comment from 5 years ago:

> The main difference is that the Tensor containing the gradients will not be reallocated at every backward pass. Since memory allocation is quite expensive (especially on GPU), this is much more efficient.
>
> There are other subtle differences between the two like some optimizers that behave differently if a gradient is 0 or None. It am sure there are other places that behave like that.

...On the other hand, inplace operations are usually not considered necessary or even suboptimal in some cases, so I guess YMMV w.r.t. the performance of either method.

Answer (score 3):

In simple terms We need [ZERO_GRAD](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.Optimizer.zero_grad.html#torch.optim.Optimizer.zero_grad)

because when we start a training loop, we do not want past gardients or past results to interfere with our current results beacuse how PyTorch works as it collects/accumulates the gradients on backpropagation and if the past results may mixup and give us the wrong results so we set the gradient to zero every time we  go through the loop.
Here is a example:

```
    # let us write a training loop
    torch.manual_seed(42)
    
    epochs = 200
    for epoch in range(epochs):
      model_1.train()
    
      y_pred = model_1(X_train)
    
      loss = loss_fn(y_pred,y_train)
    
      optimizer.zero_grad()
    
      loss.backward()

      optimizer.step()
```

In this for loop, if we do not set the optimizer to zero every time the past value it may get add up and changes the result.
So we use zero_grad to not face the wrong accumulated results.

Answer (score 2):

`zero_grad()` restarts looping without losses from the last step if you use the gradient method for decreasing the error (or losses).

If you do not use `zero_grad()` the loss will increase not decrease as required.

For example:

If you use `zero_grad()` you will get the following output:

```
model training loss is 1.5
model training loss is 1.4
model training loss is 1.3
model training loss is 1.2
```

If you do not use `zero_grad()` you will get the following output:

```
model training loss is 1.4
model training loss is 1.9
model training loss is 2
model training loss is 2.8
model training loss is 3.5
```

Comment: This is confusing to say the least. What looping gets restarted? Loss increase/decrease is affected indirectly, it can increase when you do `.zero_grad()` and it can decrease when you don't. Where are the outputs you're showing coming from?

Comment: dear dedObed (this example for if you remove zero_grad from your correctly code), we talk about .zero_grad() function , this function only is start looping without the last result ، if loss is increasing is increasing you should be review your input ( write your problem in new topic and git me the link.

Comment: I (think I) do understand PyTorch well enough. I'm just pointing out what I perceive as flaws in you answer -- it's not clear, drawing quick conclusions, showing outputs who-knows-of-what.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to call grad_zero() alternatively one can decay the gradients for example:

```
optimizer = some_pytorch_optimizer
# decay the grads :
for group in optimizer.param_groups:
    for p in group['params']:
        if p.grad is not None:
            ''' original code from git:
            if set_to_none:
                p.grad = None
            else:
                if p.grad.grad_fn is not None:
                    p.grad.detach_()
                else:
                    p.grad.requires_grad_(False)
                p.grad.zero_()
                
            '''
            p.grad = p.grad / 2
```

this way the learning is much more continues

Answer (score 1):

It is important to visualize the losses to understand their behavior. One thing to keep in mind is that not using `zero_grad()` can lead gradients to accumulation by default:

- using `zero_grad()`:
  [image: using zero_grad()]
- not using `zero_grad()`:
  [image: notusing zero_grad()]

Answer (score 0):

During the feed forward propagation the weights are assigned to inputs and after the 1st iteration the weights are initialized what the model has learnt seeing the samples(inputs). And when we start back propagation we want to update weights in order to get minimum loss of our cost function. So we clear off our previous weights in order to obtained more better weights. This we keep doing in training and we do not perform this in testing because we have got the weights in training time which is best fitted in our data. Hope this would clear more!