# Is it possible to statically wrap/derive a parameter from another paramerter in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I often run into situations where I want to train a parameter, but that parameter only gets used by the model in a transformed form. For example, think of a simple scalar parameter defined on `(-∞, +∞)`, but the model only wants to use that parameter wrapped in a sigmoid, to constrain it to `(0, 1)` e.g. to model a probability. A naive attempt to implemented such a wrapped/derived parameter would be:

```py
class ConstrainedModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.x_raw = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(0.0))
        self.x = torch.nn.functional.sigmoid(self.x_raw)

    def forward(self) -> torch.Tensor:
        # An actual model of course would use self.x in a more sophisticated way...
        return self.x
```

The model is only really interested in using the constrained/transformed `self.x`, e.g. because it is semantically more relevant than the underlying/unstransformed `self.x_raw`. In a sense, the implementation tries to hide away `self.x_raw` because it is more confusing to think in this unconstrained parameter.

However training this model with something like this...

```py
def main():
    model = ConstrainedModel()

    opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())
    loss_func = torch.nn.MSELoss()

    y_truth = torch.tensor(0.9)

    for i in range(10000):

        y_predicted = model.forward()
        loss = loss_func.forward(y_predicted, y_truth)
        print(f"iteration: {i+1}    loss: {loss.item()}    x: {model.x.item()}")

        loss.backward()

        opt.step()
        opt.zero_grad()
```

... will fail in the second iteration with the infamous error:

> RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time [...]

Note that the reason here is different from the common causes ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48274929/1804173), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61015728/1804173)) of this error: In this case the issue is hidden by the fact that the model has wrapped/derived `self.x` from `self.x_raw` in its constructor, which leads to holding a reference to something from the previous backwards pass.

My standard work-around is to make all wrapping repeatedly/dynamically only inside `forward`, i.e., this would work:

```py
class ConstrainedModelWorkAround(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.x_raw = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(0.0))

    def forward(self) -> torch.Tensor:
        x = torch.nn.functional.sigmoid(self.x_raw)
        return x
```

But now the model only exposes `model.x_raw` and lacks the more human-friendly `model.x` representation of the parameter, which would be nicer to work with inside the model code, and which would also be more convenient to monitor during training (e.g. in a tensorboard display).

I'm wondering if I'm missing a trick how to achieve a kind of "static" wrapping of parameters instead?

Answer (score 1):

The concept you're describing doesn't exist in pytorch.

For example, your first set up

```py
class ConstrainedModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.x_raw = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(0.0))
        self.x = torch.nn.functional.sigmoid(self.x_raw)
```

isn't actually doing what you want. It's not "wrapping" the parameter in the sigmoid function. It just applies the sigmoid function once when you instantiate the model. This setup doesn't do anything to constrain the range of the parameter.

If you really wanted to avoid the sigmoid in the forward pass, you could manually clip the value of your parameter to `(0, 1)` after every update step. However, applying the sigmoid in the forward pass is the more standard approach for this sort of thing.

Clipping parameters tends to cause more numerical instability in the model. The sigmoid function is nice because it allows the pre-sigmoid logit to fluctuate along the full range of `(-∞, +∞)` while still maintaining the `(0, 1)` property of the sigmoid output.

Clipping values is way less computationally intensive than computing a sigmoid, which involves exponentiation and division. Nonetheless, you see the sigmoid used in practice (ie LSTMs) because it is more stable and has nice properties for gradient based optimization.