# IndexError: index out of range in self and RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I have a problem when I run **[model.py](https://github.com/Dimas263/Research_NLP_Biomedical_Relation_Extraction_Bert)**

**if you don't mind can you correct my code [here](https://github.com/Dimas263/Research_NLP_Biomedical_Relation_Extraction_Bert/blob/main/nlp_relation_extraction_bert_bilstm_crf.ipynb)**

run with **CPU**

```
seq_ent = torch.cat([torch.index_select(seq_out[i,:,:],0,ids[i,:].long()).unsqueeze(0) for i in range(batch_size)], 0) # [batchsize, 4, 768]

IndexError: index out of range in self
```

run with **GPU**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-43fe30517134> in <module>()
     98       # print(train_data['ids'].shape)
     99 
--> 100       token_ids = train_data['token_ids'].to(device)
    101       attention_masks = train_data['attention_masks'].to(device)
    102       token_type_ids = train_data['token_type_ids'].to(device)

RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
```

Comment: For CUDA error, I recommend setting your device to 'cpu'.

Comment: Thank you, but when set device to 'CPU' I still get error' with IndexError: index out of range in self

Comment: suggestions: (1) write this line as cycle with several individual operations inside, so you'd see which part triggers error. (2) search for and check out similar cases, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62081155/pytorch-indexerror-index-out-of-range-in-self-how-to-solve