# ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([16])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([16, 5]))

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I'm using BERT for multi-label classification. The code ran fine yesterday but when I run it today I'm getting the error above and I've no idea why. I've used it with both a new smaller dataset and the dataset from yesterday and it gives the same error with each. Other than changing a filename for switching datasets there where no changes to the code from when I shut down last night to when I opened it this morning

```
# This training code is based on the `run_glue.py` script here:
# https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/5bfcd0485ece086ebcbed2d008813037968a9e58/examples/run_glue.py#L128

seed_val = r_seed

random.seed(seed_val)
np.random.seed(seed_val)
torch.manual_seed(seed_val)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed_val)

# We'll store a number of quantities such as training and validation loss, 
# validation accuracy, and timings.
training_stats = []

# Measure the total training time for the whole run.
total_t0 = time.time()

# For each epoch...
for epoch_i in range(0, epochs):
    
    # ========================================
    #               Training
    # ========================================
    
    # Perform one full pass over the training set.

    print("")
    print('======== Epoch {:} / {:} ========'.format(epoch_i + 1, epochs))
    print('Training...')

    # Measure how long the training epoch takes.
    t0 = time.time()

    # Reset the total loss for this epoch.
    total_train_loss = 0

    # Put the model into training mode. Don't be mislead--the call to 
    # `train` just changes the *mode*, it doesn't *perform* the training.
    # `dropout` and `batchnorm` layers behave differently during training
    # vs. test (source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51433378/what-does-model-train-do-in-pytorch)
    model.train()

    # For each batch of training data...
    for step, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):

        # Progress update every 200 batches.
        if step % 200 == 0 and not step == 0:
            # Calculate elapsed time in minutes.
            elapsed = format_time(time.time() - t0)
            
            # Report progress.
            print('  Batch {:>5,}  of  {:>5,}.    Elapsed: {:}.'.format(step, len(train_dataloader), elapsed))

        # Unpack this training batch from our dataloader. 
        #
        # As we unpack the batch, we'll also copy each tensor to the GPU using the 
        # `to` method.
        #
        # `batch` contains three pytorch tensors:
        #   [0]: input ids 
        #   [1]: attention masks
        #   [2]: labels 
        b_input_ids = batch[0].to(device)
        b_input_mask = batch[1].to(device)
        b_labels = batch[2].to(device)

        # Always clear any previously calculated gradients before performing a
        # backward pass. PyTorch doesn't do this automatically because 
        # accumulating the gradients is "convenient while training RNNs". 
        # (source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001598/why-do-we-need-to-call-zero-grad-in-pytorch)
        model.zero_grad()        

        # Perform a forward pass (evaluate the model on this training batch).
        # In PyTorch, calling `model` will in turn call the model's `forward` 
        # function and pass down the arguments. The `forward` function is 
        # documented here: 
        # https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#bertforsequenceclassification
        # The results are returned in a results object, documented here:
        # https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/output.html#transformers.modeling_outputs.SequenceClassifierOutput
        # Specifically, we'll get the loss (because we provided labels) and the
        # "logits"--the model outputs prior to activation.
        result = model(b_input_ids, 
                       token_type_ids=None, 
                       attention_mask=b_input_mask, 
                       labels=b_labels,
                       return_dict=True)

        loss = result.loss
        logits = result.logits

        # Accumulate the training loss over all of the batches so that we can
        # calculate the average loss at the end. `loss` is a Tensor containing a
        # single value; the `.item()` function just returns the Python value 
        # from the tensor.
        total_train_loss += loss.item()

        # Perform a backward pass to calculate the gradients.
        loss.backward()

        # Clip the norm of the gradients to 1.0.
        # This is to help prevent the "exploding gradients" problem.
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1.0)

        # Update parameters and take a step using the computed gradient.
        # The optimizer dictates the "update rule"--how the parameters are
        # modified based on their gradients, the learning rate, etc.
        optimizer.step()

        # Update the learning rate.
        scheduler.step()

    # Calculate the average loss over all of the batches.
    avg_train_loss = total_train_loss / len(train_dataloader)            
    
    # Measure how long this epoch took.
    training_time = format_time(time.time() - t0)

    print("")
    print("  Average training loss: {0:.2f}".format(avg_train_loss))
    print("  Training epcoh took: {:}".format(training_time))
        
    # ========================================
    #               Validation
    # ========================================
    # After the completion of each training epoch, measure our performance on
    # our validation set.

    print("")
    print("Running Validation...")

    t0 = time.time()

    # Put the model in evaluation mode--the dropout layers behave differently
    # during evaluation.
    model.eval()

    # Tracking variables 
    total_eval_accuracy = 0
    total_eval_loss = 0
    nb_eval_steps = 0

    # Evaluate data for one epoch
    for batch in validation_dataloader:
        
        # Unpack this training batch from our dataloader. 
        #
        # As we unpack the batch, we'll also copy each tensor to the GPU using 
        # the `to` method.
        #
        # `batch` contains three pytorch tensors:
        #   [0]: input ids 
        #   [1]: attention masks
        #   [2]: labels 
        b_input_ids = batch[0].to(device)
        b_input_mask = batch[1].to(device)
        b_labels = batch[2].to(device)
        
        # Tell pytorch not to bother with constructing the compute graph during
        # the forward pass, since this is only needed for backprop (training).
        with torch.no_grad():        

            # Forward pass, calculate logit predictions.
            # token_type_ids is the same as the "segment ids", which 
            # differentiates sentence 1 and 2 in 2-sentence tasks.
            result = model(b_input_ids, 
                           token_type_ids=None, 
                           attention_mask=b_input_mask,
                           labels=b_labels,
                           return_dict=True)

        # Get the loss and "logits" output by the model. The "logits" are the 
        # output values prior to applying an activation function like the 
        # softmax.
        loss = result.loss
        logits = result.logits
            
        # Accumulate the validation loss.
        total_eval_loss += loss.item()

        # Move logits and labels to CPU
        logits = logits.detach().cpu().numpy()
        label_ids = b_labels.to('cpu').numpy()

        # Calculate the accuracy for this batch of test sentences, and
        # accumulate it over all batches.
        total_eval_accuracy += flat_accuracy(logits, label_ids)
        

    # Report the final accuracy for this validation run.
    avg_val_accuracy = total_eval_accuracy / len(validation_dataloader)
    print("  Accuracy: {0:.2f}".format(avg_val_accuracy))

    # Calculate the average loss over all of the batches.
    avg_val_loss = total_eval_loss / len(validation_dataloader)
    
    # Measure how long the validation run took.
    validation_time = format_time(time.time() - t0)
    
    print("  Validation Loss: {0:.2f}".format(avg_val_loss))
    print("  Validation took: {:}".format(validation_time))

    # Record all statistics from this epoch.
    training_stats.append(
        {
            'epoch': epoch_i + 1,
            'Training Loss': avg_train_loss,
            'Valid. Loss': avg_val_loss,
            'Valid. Accur.': avg_val_accuracy,
            'Training Time': training_time,
            'Validation Time': validation_time
        }
    )

print("")
print("Training complete!")

print("Total training took {:} (h:mm:ss)".format(format_time(time.time()-total_t0)))
```

Full error code

```
ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([16])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([16, 5]))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13276/1507217001.py in <module>
     82         # "logits"--the model outputs prior to activation.
     83 
---> 84         result = model(b_input_ids, 
     85                        token_type_ids=None,
     86                        attention_mask=b_input_mask,

C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1049         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1050                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1051             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1052         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1053         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\bert\modeling_bert.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, labels, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
   1558             elif self.config.problem_type == "multi_label_classification":
   1559                 loss_fct = BCEWithLogitsLoss()
-> 1560                 loss = loss_fct(logits, labels)
   1561         if not return_dict:
   1562             output = (logits,) + outputs[2:]

C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1049         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1050                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1051             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1052         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1053         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py in forward(self, input, target)
    711 
    712     def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 713         return F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target,
    714                                                   self.weight,
    715                                                   pos_weight=self.pos_weight,

C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py in binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target, weight, size_average, reduce, reduction, pos_weight)
   2956 
   2957     if not (target.size() == input.size()):
-> 2958         raise ValueError("Target size ({}) must be the same as input size ({})".format(target.size(), input.size()))
   2959 
   2960     return torch.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target, weight, pos_weight, reduction_enum)

ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([16])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([16, 5]))
```

Comment: Kindly provide, the model definition and example of input data

Comment: If you may share the vectorization part of the code and your model class, this will make it easier for people to help.