# Doc-Classification (Pytorch, Bert), how to change the training/validation loop to work for multilabel case

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model

I am trying to make `BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained()` work for multilabel. Since the code I found online is for binary label case.
I have document classification with 12 labels. Using Bert Language model as pytorch model.

what should I do to make it work for multilabel. I get this error, when I run it initially without changing the train/val loop

> ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([32])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([32, 12]))

I assume I have to change the input since the target is [32,12]. But how to do this?

Edit: Full output

```
======== Epoch 1 / 4 ========
Training...
torch.Size([32, 64])
tensor([[1, 1, 1,  ..., 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
    ...,
    [1, 1, 1,  ..., 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1,  ..., 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1,  ..., 1, 1, 1]], device='cuda:0')
tensor([ 9.,  9.,  3.,  8.,  9., 10.,  4.,  3.,  4.,  4.,  9.,  0.,  9.,  9.,
    11.,  3.,  9.,  9.,  3.,  4.,  4.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.,  6.,  4.,  0.,
    10.,  3.,  4.,  1.], dtype=torch.float64)
```

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-25-ac7a3b802ac2> in <module>
 90         # Specifically, we'll get the loss (because we provided labels) and the
 91         # "logits"--the model outputs prior to activation.
---> 92         result = model(b_input_ids, 
 93                        token_type_ids=None,
 94                        attention_mask=b_input_mask, 4 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target, weight, size_average, reduce, reduction, pos_weight)


3158     3159     if not (target.size() == input.size()):
-> 3160         raise ValueError("Target size ({}) must be the same as input size ({})".format(target.size(), input.size()))    3161     3162 return torch.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target, weight, pos_weight, reduction_enum)

ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([32])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([32, 12]))
```

the code:

```
from transformers import BertForSequenceClassification, AdamW, BertConfig
# Load BertForSequenceClassification, the pretrained BERT model with a single 
# linear classification layer on top. 
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
"bert-base-uncased", # Use the 12-layer BERT model, with an uncased vocab.
num_labels = 2, # The number of output labels--2 for binary classification.
                # You can increase this for multi-class tasks.   
output_attentions = False, # Whether the model returns attentions weights.
output_hidden_states = False, # Whether the model returns all hidden-states.
)

# Tell pytorch to run this model on the GPU.
model.cuda()

optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(),
              lr = 2e-5, # args.learning_rate - default is 5e-5, our notebook had 2e-5
              eps = 1e-8 # args.adam_epsilon  - default is 1e-8.
            )
from transformers import get_linear_schedule_with_warmup




total_steps = len(train_dataloader) * epochs

# Create the learning rate scheduler.
scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(optimizer, 
                                        num_warmup_steps = 0, # Default value in run_glue.py
                                        num_training_steps = total_steps)
```

```
import random
import numpy as np

# This training code is based on the `run_glue.py` script here:
# https://github.com/huggingface/transformer/blob/5bfcd0485ece086ebcbed2d008813037968a9e58/examples/run_glue.py#L128

# Set the seed value all over the place to make this reproducible.
seed_val = 42

random.seed(seed_val)
np.random.seed(seed_val)
torch.manual_seed(seed_val)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed_val)

# We'll store a number of quantities such as training and validation loss, 
# validation accuracy, and timings.
training_stats = []

# Measure the total training time for the whole run.
total_t0 = time.time()

# For each epoch...
for epoch_i in range(0, epochs):

    # ========================================
    #               Training
    # ========================================

    # Perform one full pass over the training set.

    print("")
    print('======== Epoch {:} / {:} ========'.format(epoch_i + 1, epochs))
    print('Training...')

    # Measure how long the training epoch takes.
    t0 = time.time()

    # Reset the total loss for this epoch.
    total_train_loss = 0

    # Put the model into training mode. Don't be mislead--the call to 
    # `train` just changes the *mode*, it doesn't *perform* the training.
    # `dropout` and `batchnorm` layers behave differently during training
    # vs. test (source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51433378/what-does-model-train-do-in-pytorch)
    model.train()

    # For each batch of training data...
    for step, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):

        # Progress update every 40 batches.
        if step % 40 == 0 and not step == 0:
            # Calculate elapsed time in minutes.
            elapsed = format_time(time.time() - t0)
        
            # Report progress.
            print('  Batch {:>5,}  of  {:>5,}.    Elapsed: {:}.'.format(step, len(train_dataloader), elapsed))

        # Unpack this training batch from our dataloader. 
        #
        # As we unpack the batch, we'll also copy each tensor to the GPU using the 
        # `to` method.
        #
        # `batch` contains three pytorch tensors:
        #   [0]: input ids 
        #   [1]: attention masks
        #   [2]: labels 
        b_input_ids = batch[0].to(device)
        b_input_mask = batch[1].to(device)
        b_labels = batch[2].to(device)

    # Always clear any previously calculated gradients before performing a
    # backward pass. PyTorch doesn't do this automatically because 
    # accumulating the gradients is "convenient while training RNNs". 
    # (source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001598/why-do-we-need-to-call-zero-grad-in-pytorch)
    model.zero_grad()        

    # Perform a forward pass (evaluate the model on this training batch).
    # In PyTorch, calling `model` will in turn call the model's `forward` 
    # function and pass down the arguments. The `forward` function is 
    # documented here: 
    # https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#bertforsequenceclassification
    # The results are returned in a results object, documented here:
    # https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/output.html#transformers.modeling_outputs.SequenceClassifierOutput
    # Specifically, we'll get the loss (because we provided labels) and the
    # "logits"--the model outputs prior to activation.
    result = model(b_input_ids, 
                   token_type_ids=None, 
                   attention_mask=b_input_mask, 
                   labels=b_labels,
                   return_dict=True)

    loss = result.loss
    logits = result.logits

    # Accumulate the training loss over all of the batches so that we can
    # calculate the average loss at the end. `loss` is a Tensor containing a
    # single value; the `.item()` function just returns the Python value 
    # from the tensor.
    total_train_loss += loss.item()

    # Perform a backward pass to calculate the gradients.
    loss.backward()

    # Clip the norm of the gradients to 1.0.
    # This is to help prevent the "exploding gradients" problem.
    torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1.0)

    # Update parameters and take a step using the computed gradient.
    # The optimizer dictates the "update rule"--how the parameters are
    # modified based on their gradients, the learning rate, etc.
    optimizer.step()

    # Update the learning rate.
    scheduler.step()

# Calculate the average loss over all of the batches.
avg_train_loss = total_train_loss / len(train_dataloader)            

# Measure how long this epoch took.
training_time = format_time(time.time() - t0)

print("")
print("  Average training loss: {0:.2f}".format(avg_train_loss))
print("  Training epcoh took: {:}".format(training_time))
    
# ========================================
#               Validation
# ========================================
# After the completion of each training epoch, measure our performance on
# our validation set.

print("")
print("Running Validation...")

t0 = time.time()

# Put the model in evaluation mode--the dropout layers behave differently
# during evaluation.
model.eval()

# Tracking variables 
total_eval_accuracy = 0
total_eval_loss = 0
nb_eval_steps = 0

# Evaluate data for one epoch
for batch in validation_dataloader:
    
    # Unpack this training batch from our dataloader. 
    #
    # As we unpack the batch, we'll also copy each tensor to the GPU using 
    # the `to` method.
    #
    # `batch` contains three pytorch tensors:
    #   [0]: input ids 
    #   [1]: attention masks
    #   [2]: labels 
    b_input_ids = batch[0].to(device)
    b_input_mask = batch[1].to(device)
    b_labels = batch[2].to(device)
    
    # Tell pytorch not to bother with constructing the compute graph during
    # the forward pass, since this is only needed for backprop (training).
    with torch.no_grad():        

        # Forward pass, calculate logit predictions.
        # token_type_ids is the same as the "segment ids", which 
        # differentiates sentence 1 and 2 in 2-sentence tasks.
        result = model(b_input_ids, 
                       token_type_ids=None, 
                       attention_mask=b_input_mask,
                       labels=b_labels,
                       return_dict=True)

    # Get the loss and "logits" output by the model. The "logits" are the 
    # output values prior to applying an activation function like the 
    # softmax.
    loss = result.loss
    logits = result.logits
        
    # Accumulate the validation loss.
    total_eval_loss += loss.item()

    # Move logits and labels to CPU
    logits = logits.detach().cpu().numpy()
    label_ids = b_labels.to('cpu').numpy()

    # Calculate the accuracy for this batch of test sentences, and
    # accumulate it over all batches.
    total_eval_accuracy += flat_accuracy(logits, label_ids)
    

# Report the final accuracy for this validation run.
avg_val_accuracy = total_eval_accuracy / len(validation_dataloader)
print("  Accuracy: {0:.2f}".format(avg_val_accuracy))

# Calculate the average loss over all of the batches.
avg_val_loss = total_eval_loss / len(validation_dataloader)

# Measure how long the validation run took.
validation_time = format_time(time.time() - t0)

print("  Validation Loss: {0:.2f}".format(avg_val_loss))
print("  Validation took: {:}".format(validation_time))

# Record all statistics from this epoch.
training_stats.append(
    {
        'epoch': epoch_i + 1,
        'Training Loss': avg_train_loss,
        'Valid. Loss': avg_val_loss,
        'Valid. Accur.': avg_val_accuracy,
        'Training Time': training_time,
        'Validation Time': validation_time
    }
)

print("")
print("Training complete!")

print("Total training took {:} (h:mm:ss)".format(format_time(time.time()-total_t0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not well-versed in this but I guess this would help. In the code you have posted, you haven't changed the num_labels=12, it is only 2. if you have 12 classes, then maybe you need to change it right? Let me know if it works. Also, could you share the answer to the previously posted question in [calculating average word embedding Glove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74620001/calculating-average-word-embedding-glove)? I also want to learn how to implement it.